# How to set custom pin image in Mapview swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview, mkannotationview

```
@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    map.delegate = self
    showAlarms()
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func showAlarms(){

    map.region.center.latitude = 10.733051
    map.region.center.longitude = 76.763042
    map.region.span.latitudeDelta = 1
    map.region.span.longitudeDelta = 1


}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
             viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        //pinView!.animatesDrop = true
        pinView!.image = UIImage(named:"annotation")!

    }
    else {
        pinView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

I need to show to a custom pin image for my mapview in swift ios. The custom image is not loading neither the pin. I have an image named "annotation" which I need to load in my mapview.

Comment: The delegate method of viewForAnnotation is Called for You or not.

Comment: @KiritModi. I don't thinks so. It's showing only the map and nothing else. Please help.

Comment: You are code in swift 3

Comment: @KiritModi I am using swift3 but the code is not working.

Comment: Added new code of showAlarms.

Comment: @KiritModi. I have added the code. But it's still not working. But when I checked the answer given by Lalit Kumar it is working. But when the mapview loads full map is showing. I need to show only the area near my cordinates. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133780/discussion-between-rakesh-and-kirit-modi).

Comment: Use MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView to have custom pin image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  mapview.delegate = self

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {
    return nil
}

 let annotationIdentifier = "Identifier"
 var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?
 if let dequeuedAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationIdentifier) {
    annotationView = dequeuedAnnotationView
    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
}
else {
    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
    annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
}

 if let annotationView = annotationView {

    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImagename”)
}
  return annotationView
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your custom MKAnnotationView and set the image inside:

```
class myCustomAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView {

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        guard let annotation = newValue else {return}
        switch annotation {
        case is myCustomMKAnnotation:
            self.canShowCallout = true 
            self.image = #yourimage
            self.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.image!.size.height / 2)
            break
        default:
            return
        }
        self.setAnimationLayer()
    }
}
```

And then all you need to do it:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { return nil }
    guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else {


    let annotationIdentifier = "Identifier"
    if let myAnnotation = annotation as? myCustomMKAnnotation {
        let annotation = myCustomAnnotationView(annotation: siteAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
        return annotation
    }
    return nil
}
```

I think it looks cleaner like that